# Why ListPicker always showing in FullscreenOnly mode

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone, listpicker

I am using a ListPicker and it is always showing in FullscreenOnly mode even if i change the ExpansionMode to ExpansionAllowed.

But in other page the same code is working properly.

Why is this strange behaviour happening?

Comment: You said you solved the problem, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Assuming this is the Windows Phone Toolkit ListPicker)

If your list is longer than 5 items then it will open in FullScreenMode. It isn't possible to change this threshold value.

So, this one will expand:

```
<toolkit:ListPicker Header="Background">
    <sys:String>dark</sys:String>
    <sys:String>light</sys:String>
    <sys:String>dazzle</sys:String>
    <sys:String>4</sys:String>
    <sys:String>5</sys:String>
</toolkit:ListPicker>
```

This one will always be full screen:

```
<toolkit:ListPicker Header="Background">
    <sys:String>dark</sys:String>
    <sys:String>light</sys:String>
    <sys:String>dazzle</sys:String>
    <sys:String>4</sys:String>
    <sys:String>5</sys:String>
    <sys:String>6</sys:String>
</toolkit:ListPicker>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to expand more then 5 elements. You must set ItemCountThreshold.

I set it in view model in method where I set collection's items.

```
Collection = new ObservableCollection<Item>
{
    new Item();
    new Item();
    new Item();
    new Item();
    new Item();
    new Item();
}
CollectionItemsCount = Collection.Count;
```

And binding in xaml:

```
<toolkit:ListPicker ExpansionMode="ExpansionAllowed" ItemsSource="{Binding Collection}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}" ItemCountThreshold="{Binding CollectionItemsCount}">
(...)
```